# Conditional form output - using react forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a conditional form output without creating a ridiculous amount of nested if statements. 
These are the key code the forms are changing.

```
         class MasterForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currentStep: 1,
      notice:  'No',
      delay: 'No',
      qualifying: 'Enter Days Here',
      onegreater: 'Other',
      days_28: 'No',
      EoTClaim: 'No',
      EoTdate : 'No',
      EoTEvidence : 'No'


    }
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })    
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { notice, delay, qualifying, onegreater, days_28, EoTClaim, EoTdate, EoTEvidence } = this.state

 const _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

// a and b are javascript Date objects
function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
  // Discard the time and time-zone information.
  const utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
  const utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());

  return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
}

// test it
const a = new Date(days_28),
    b = new Date(EoTdate),
    difference = dateDiffInDays(a, b);

function claimGranted(){
  return notice === 'Yes'
    && delay === 'Yes'
    && onegreater !== 'Other'
    && EoTClaim === 'Yes'
    && EoTEvidence === 'Yes'
    && difference < 28;
}


function Fail_text(notice, delay, onegreater, EoTClaim, EoTEvidence, difference){
  var fail = "The Contractor is not entitled to an Extension of Time because: \n"
  if (notice  === "No") {
  t_n = "You did not receive prompt written notice of this delay event \n ";
} else {t_n = "Nothing"}
  /*var t_n = (notice === "No") ? "":"You did not receive prompt written notice of this delay event \n "*/ //etc     
  return alert(fail+t_n+t_d+t_o+t_Eot+t_eE+t_dif)
}

if (claimGranted()) {
    alert(`Claim Granted: The contractor is entitled to an Extension of Time of ${qualifying} days.`);
} else Fail_text();
  }

  /* This result varies depending on which requirement is not satisfied and can either have only 1 reason or multiple reasons.
```

e.g. 
If only Q 1 is a red answer then it should read:
You did not receive prompt written notice of this delay event”

*/

My approach to solving this issue is,

Creating dual functions to answer each type of submission.

Sort of worked this out currently - appreciate the help, although it didn't address the original question, it did lead me to clean up my code.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you have multiple values you are testing against so a `switch` would not benefit you here.  Also you are using the bitwise `&` operator and not the `&&` conditional operator so be careful and make sure that's actually what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks Deryck . How do i give the cause of the failure if the claim is not granted?

Comment: you test each condition individually and report the error(s) appropriately

Comment: How would you report the errors appropriately?

Comment: @Deryck I've made some changes above to try and add what you had mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A switch won't help you here. Switches are appropriate for cases where there are several possible values for a single variable and you want to handle each one differently. You can make this code more readable by adding a helper function to check whether or not the claim is granted and invoke that in your conditional instead. This is just a basic example below, you could also add it as a method on your component class (assuming this is from a React app based on the reference to `this.state`).

```
function claimGranted(){
  return this.state.notice === 'Yes'
    && this.state.delay === 'Yes'
    && this.state.onegreater !== 'Other'
    && this.state.EoTClaim === 'Yes'
    && this.state.EoTEvidence === 'Yes'
    && this.state.difference < 28;
}

if (claimGranted()) {
    alert(`Claim Granted: The contractor is entitled to an Extension of Time of ${qualifying} days.`);
} else {
    alert(`The Contractor is not entitled to an Extension of Time because: You did not receive prompt written notice of this delay event`);
}
```

Comment: It would also make your code cleaner if you used booleans instead of 'Yes' and 'No' for these values. You can have your form display readable options while submitting an actual value of 1 or 0, which makes life a lot easier. In that case you could just do `this.state.notice && this.state.delay && this.state.EoTClaim && this.state.EoTEvidence && this.state.onegreater !== 'Other' && this.state.difference < 28`

Comment: Oh wow - Thanks so much Kayla, I still have a lot to learn, it's always amazing how much help there is online.

Comment: I was looking to get conditional outputs for each of the different not entitled code. I'll make my explanation better above. Thanks!